# I'm unable to get my Angular Service to connect

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, service

I'm trying to hook up a simple service that queries a php file. The user inputs a username and password, and clicks a button that runs this function (passing in $scope.password):

```
$scope.loginFunction = function(){
    loginService.getLogin().then(function(response){
      $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
    }, function(error){
      $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
    });
};
```

The service looks like this:

```
.service('loginService', ['$http', '$q', '$rootScope', function($http, $q, $rootScope){
var getLogin = function(scope) {
  $http.post('login.php'), {
      password: $scope.password
  }, function (success) {
      console.log("Login result: " + success);
  }, function (error) {
      console.log("Couldn't complete the login request.");
  } 
  return({ 
    getLogin: getLogin
  })  
}
```

}])

The error I get is: "TypeError: loginService.getLogin is not a function"

But at the top of my controller with the function, I have:

```
  myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$filter', 'loginService', function myController($scope, $rootScope, $filter, loginService) {
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?
Thanks!

Sorry, here is login.php:

```
    <? echo $_POST['password'] == 'test123' ? true : false ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like..

`myApp.service('loginService', ['$http', '$q', '$rootScope', function($http, $q, $rootScope){
    var service = {
        getLogin: function(scope) {
            $http.post('login.php'), {
              password: $scope.password
            }, function (success) {
              console.log("Login result: " + success);
            }, function (error) {
              console.log("Couldn't complete the login request.");
            } 
        }
    };

    return service;
}`

Comment: I think this one is making progress for me. But now it is saying $scope is not defined at line 
    password: $scope.password

Answer (score 0):

`var getLogin` how you have it is a private function.  This will work for you.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.service("loginService", ["$http","$q", function($http, $q) {
    var loginService = this;

    loginService.getLogin = function(password) {
        //use this if you'd like to return promise
        var defer = $q.defer();

        //put password into a json object
        var payload = {
            password: password;
        };

        //upload payload to server, content-type must be json
        $http.post("url/to/controller", payload, {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        }).then(function(data){
            defer.resolve(data); //success... resolve
        }, function(error) {
            defer.reject(error); //error... reject it
        });

        return defer.promise; //return the promise
    }

    return loginService;
}]);
```

Comment: I tried this one, and it would never come back with a positive response.  What is the benefit of putting the password in a json over a php file?

Comment: What are you passing in as password when you call `loginService.getLogin(...)`?  Are you absolutely sure the passwords match?

Comment: So, I got the errors to go away. Where do I actually store the password though? Is it in this javascript file? Right now it is taking any password I give it.

Comment: The password comes from your model.  `$scope.password = "blah";`  Then in your controller, call the service, passing in the password like this:  `loginService.getLogin($scope.password).then(function(data){//success},function(error){//error});`

Comment: Sorry, I mean how do I validate the password (from $scope from the user's input), with the password in my index.php file?